# LLVM Compiler 2.0: Warning with "using namespace std;"

Tags: c++, xcode, namespaces, llvm, clang

In Xcode using LLVM 2.0, when I put the line `using namespace std;` in my C++ code, I get this warning:

> Semantic Issue
>       Using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'

Is there a way to fix this?  Why is it giving that warning?

Comment: Are you putting *just* that line?

Comment: Do you include any headers that have that namespace?

Comment: Xcode 4 is still under NDA; you should ask this question in Apple's beta dev forum, it's the only forum the NDA you entered into with Apple permits you to ask. (https://devforums.apple.com/community/xcode4 -- your apple dev program login is required to read/post)

Comment: GCC allows a file to have `using namespace std;` without any standard includes. This is not conforming, so clang warns you.

Comment: It does contain other includes, for example `using namespace std;` and then `#include <iostream>`.  The other one is `#include "sqlite3.h"`.  The class is complete; it happens in any C++ header I add `using namespace std;` to.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you included any standard header files? Otherwise the compiler doesn't know about `namespace std`.

Please post more code to clarify.

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out.  You're right, the line `using namespace std;` was the first line (besides the #ifndef and #define statements of course) in the file; I moved it after the line `#include <iostream>` and it eliminated the warning.  GCC never gave that warning, so I never thought about it before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Moving the using namespace std to after the #include can eliminate this warning.

Answer (score 7):

i solved this problem like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/// This function is used to ensure that a floating point number is
/// not a NaN or infinity.
inline bool b2IsValid(float32 x)
{
    if (x != x)
    {
        // NaN.
        return false;
    }
    float32 infinity = std::numeric_limits <float32>::infinity();
    return -infinity < x && x < infinity;
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see that this question is pretty old, but for anyone checking this out in the future, I wanted to add this link from the LLVM documentation as a supplement to the discussion and for poeple looking for more info:

[LLVM Coding Standards: Do Not use using namespace std;](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#do-not-use-using-namespace-std)

I believe that the title is pretty indicative of why I've shared it to help with this question.

> In LLVM, we prefer to explicitly prefix all identifiers from the standard namespace with an “std::” prefix, rather than rely on “using namespace std;”.
>
> In header files, adding a 'using namespace XXX' directive pollutes the namespace of any source file that #includes the header. This is clearly a bad thing.

Edit:
So instead if using 'using std namespace;' explicitly type std:: for every case where you with to use the standard library. It avoids conflicts with source file namespaces. This is what the quote above from the article advises.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13390173)

Comment: I'm at work and just trying to help other people in similar situations by providing a useful piece of information that addresses this exact issue. I think the response adds to the answers already provided. If this is problematic I will just take it down. If it was me asking this question, I would wish someone shared that statement from llvm with me.

Comment: @cpburnz I guess I'm new to the style that help is asked to be in because to me it would be useful. Specifically, what more could I have added to this unclear answer? It is intended as more of an alternative suggestion to answers already posted.

Comment: It is useful to the people who are less frequent on SO, but fuzz to those who spend considerable time interacting with these questions, hence why the vets enforce this. It's a question of cleanliness and order.